# How to copy data from non-linked to linked table in Access 2010 using VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, odbc

So what I'm trying to do is to either copy data from an Access local table to a linked table on a SQL Server. I'd like this to work via a macro so it can be triggered upon opening a report. Or I could just bypass the linked table and insert directly to the remote server.

What I'm having a difficult time finding is the proper syntax to accomplish this. It should be very easy  but apparently it's not.

```vb
Public Sub CopyPT()
Dim strSQL As String

Dim strConnect As String
Dim strDatabase As String
Dim strTableName As String

ODBC_String = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=aaa;DATABASE=bbb;UID=ccc;PWD=ddd;" _
                & "LANGUAGE=us_english;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=No"

' Id also like to truncate the Destination table here too
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO dbo_DESTINATION_TABLE IN [" & ODBC_String & "]" _
           & " FROM [ACCESS_LOCAL_TABLE];"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

MsgBox "Success!"
End Sub
```

Either I need to get the proper format for the `IN` statement, which doesn't appear to have ODBC option, or I need another method to copy to the linked table. Such a simple copy and paste line by line macro - which I also can't find anywhere since most sane people would just write a query.

Thanks!

Comment: Terminology is unclear here. Linked tables are objects inside MS Access whose data sources are external. If you have linked SQL Server tables inside Access, you can run in any DML SQL statement (Select, Insert, Delete, Update) as if they were local tables.

Comment: I wish that were true. Whenever I try I get the error: Query input must contain at least one table or query. (Error 3067)

Comment: It is true. You are not mentioning if you use actual linked tables. This error indicates no such table exists as either local or linked by that name. Are there any globe icons under Tables in Navigation Pane? Did you set up such linked tables under External Data tab / ODBC?